# P5.js - 'n %' in fill color

Tags: javascript, colors, processing.js, p5.js

Looking at p5.js examples, I was wondering what the 'n %' does in the fill in this example:

```
/**
* Based on a paper here:
* http://algorithmicbotany.org/papers/abop/abop-ch4.pdf
*/

var n = 0;
var c = 10;

function setup() {
 createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
 angleMode(DEGREES);
 colorMode(HSB);
 background(0);
}

function draw() {
var a = n * 137.5; //var a = n * 137.5;
var r = c * sqrt(n);

var x = r * cos(a) + width / 2;
var y = r * sin(a) + height /2;

fill(n % 256, 255, 255);
noStroke();
ellipse(x, y, 8, 8);

 n++;
}
```

I am very curious about how the rainbow effect is achieved.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised a Google search didn't return any results.

This is the [modulo operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation), which basically gives you the remainder left over after dividing a number by another number.

Try putting together an example program that tests out exactly what the operator does.